# Why does URLEncodedFormat() in CFML encodes valid URL characters?

Tags: coldfusion, urlencode

What are the reasons behind `URLEncodedFormat()` escaping valid URL characters?

valid characters:

```
- _ . ! ~ * " ( )
```

The [CF8 Doc](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/functions_t-z_10.html) said, "[`URLEncodedFormat()` escapes] non-alphanumeric characters with equivalent hexadecimal escape sequences."  However, why escape valid URL characters?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are valid, but it seems pretty normal to me that if you ask a programming language to url encode a string that it converts all non alpha numeric chars to the hex equivalent.

ASP's Server.URLEncode() does the same and php urlencode() does too except for - and _. Also, in javascript, the encodeURIComponent() function will encode all non alpha numeric chars to hex equivalents.

This is a good idea anyway to encode all non alpha numeric characters when using user input for forming server requests to prevent anything unexpected from happening.

Answer (score 1):

Is the encoding of valid url characters causing an error or a problem?

One issue might be that by not doing so, if you embed a link with non-encoded characters in an email, the email software may decide to break the link into two lines.

If you use a fully encoded url though, the chances of this are greatly reduced.  Just one way of seeing it though.

Answer (score 0):

I could see at least in the case of " that it would be nice to have it encoded when using the URL as a link in an anchor tag.